# Variable calculation

Tags: manipulate, variable

So basically I have some code like this:

```
Manipulate[
With[{
a = h + 5,
b = a/2
}], {h, -10, 10}]
```

It works fine for a but doesn't calculate the  value of b. the output for b is simply a/2, whatever I change h to has no effect on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside that the body of your `With` is missing, you are making a basic mistake: You assume that you can use `a` inside the definition braces, when you just defined `a` there. This does not work.

You need to nest two `With` constructs to do this

```
Manipulate[With[{a = h + 5},
  With[{b = a/2},
   {a, b}]
  ], {h, -10, 10}]
```

or since version 10 or so, you can use this form (which is shown in red but that is only due to the missing support of the highlighting):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{a = h + 5}, {b = a/2}, {a, b}],
 {h, -10, 10}
]
```

Comment: I tried it and indeed it works, but where is that form of `With` documented?  Has Wolfram committed to this?

Comment: As far as I know this is an undocumented feature. Although it is really handy, the highlighter makes it impossible to use since I cannot stand when some 20 lines of correct code are marked red :) But I thought, I let you know.

Comment: @Alan Undocumented.  See: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/121